# Are mixins the right choice for storing multiple properties across distinct entity types?

Tags: python, properties, data-modeling, mixins

I am currently building a system that will aggregate posts across multiple sources. These sources have very few properties in common -- for example, the only thing in common across all the sources is that a post contains text:

```py
class Post:
    def __init__(self, text=None):
        self.text = text

    def persist(self):
        row_id = FoobarDB.insert('post', text=self.text).row_id
        id = row_id
        for superclass in type(self).mro():
            try:
                super(superclass, self).persist(id)
            except AttributeError: pass
        return id

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, id):
        post_text = FoobarDB.select('post', row_id=id).text
        post = cls(post_text)
        for superclass in cls.mro():
            try:
                super(superclass, post).load(id)
            except AttributeError: pass
        return post
```

The different sources have different features: some have tags, some have titles, some have upvotes and downvotes, etc. I was thinking of using mixins to represent all of these, so then the subclasses of `Post` specialized for different sources would inherit from `Post` and from all the mixins appropriate for that source:

```
class TwitterPost(Post, HasAuthor, HasScore): ...
class StackExchangePost(Post, HasAuthor, HasScore, HasTitle, HasTags, HasComments): ...
class XkcdPost(Post, HasTitle, HasImage): ...
class RedditPost(Post, HasTitle, HasScore, HasImage, HasComments): ...
```

The issue with this approach is that I end up with many repeating mixin declarations which, to my knowledge, cannot be optimized away without `eval` trickery:

```py
class HasAuthor:
    @property
    def author(self):
        try: return self._author
        except AttributeError: return None

    @author.setter
    def set_author(self, value): self._author = value

    def persist(self, id):
        FoobarDB.insert('author', post_id=id, author=self.author)

    def load(self, id):
        self.author = FoobarDB.select('author', post_id=id).author

class HasImage:
    @property
    def image_url(self):
        try: return self._image_url
        except AttributeError: return None

    @image_url.setter
    def set_image(self, value): self._image_url = value

    def persist(self, id):
        FoobarDB.insert('image', post_id=id, image_url=self.image_url)

    def load(self, id):
        self.image_url = FoobarDB.select('image', post_id=id).image_url
```

This code repetition suggests to me that mixins aren't the right choice here, or at least they shouldn't be used this way. Is there a better way to represent multiple classes which have some properties in common, but many properties differing?

An additional restriction is that I don't know what attributes the different posts have ahead of time; I need to be able to add new property types to accommodate new post types without having to change too much code in the base `Post` class. (In fact, one of the reasons why I imagined this approach would work is because it automatically splits the `Post` entity into many rows across different tables if the data backend is a relational database.)

Comment: Your insight is correct: usage of mixin classes is not a suitable choice, since the different posts are not necessary each other (e.g. the only thing common is that they are a "post", but in general they are different).  You probably to use composition to represent this type of data, given that a post _might_ have some attribute but not others.  [This is a relevant discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59602093/python-object-oriented-programming-composition) on this particular topic.

Comment: @metatoaster I'm not sure how composition would work in my case. I didn't mention this in my question, but I don't know all the different attributes that my posts will have ahead of time, and I want to create new types of post which have new types of attribute without editing the existing code too much. In addition, the way I'd imagine composition to work here is having properties that can be None or their corresponding datatype, but most of my datatypes are primitives like `str` and `int`.

Comment: The way having these specific types for each posts is that you are effectively forced to write all this boilerplate code to do exactly what you want, so the two wants you have (not having to write/edit existing code too much vs. specific type per post) are mutually exclusive.  With composition, you would not be forced to have `None` in place where the type is absent - the attribute may be entirely absent, it's up to you how you compose the schema together for each valid relationship.

Comment: Speaking about relationship looking at this again you might be modelling multiple one-to-one relationships (since you are using some kind of database to back your data), so I suggest you look into that direction, specifically how relationships between entities are modeled for the database platform/library you are using.

Comment: The reason I'm having many one-to-one relationships is because (as I understand it at this time) if I were to store all the attributes relating to a post in a single table, then it would have many NULLs for posts for which the attribute in question is not applicable, and every new field added would require a costly schema upgrade. My idea was to instead have many small key-value tables which get JOINed to the main `Post` table in order to retrieve all the attributes that a post _may_ have, with NULLs in the fields that this post does not have.

Comment: Yes I was already aware that's your assumption, my point is you may wish to research further down that track. NULLs for posts that don't have the field may in fact be redundant as the JOIN statements should automatically resolve that.  You may wish to look into what ORM solutions out there which will help to model what you actually want to do.